Adding Azure Machine Learning Service function on Azure Stream Analytics Jobs
I am trying to add Azure Machine Learning Service function on a streaming job using a pretrained hugging-face sentiment analysis model (cardiffnlp-twitter-roberta-base-sentiment)
While adding the function I am facing this challenge:

Function signature
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

I have deployed the endpoint for (cardiffnlp-twitter-roberta-base-sentiment) on Azure ML Studio. I am trying to integrate that on Azure Stream job, but getting this error:
Function alias
sentiment

Subscription:
<Subscription>

Azure ML Workspace:
<ML Workspace>

Deployemnts:
<deployment>

Function signature 
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source


According to this documentation, you must have an associated swagger that helps Stream Analytics understand the schema of the input and output.
To automatically generate the schema, you can provide sample input or output to the constructor and use those in input_schema or output_schema decorators.
Your run() function must have an input, optional GlobalParameters, and return results all of the type StandardPythonParameterType.
Inputs and results can be nested with the types below.

pandas
numpy
pyspark
Standard Python object

To create the required scoring script, refer to this documentation.
Also, in your case, the error refers to the parameter source, which cannot be null.
So, check your scoring script to see how the parameter source is used, and alter it correctly.

Hi @jayashankarGS - I have used a pretrained Hugging Face model (azureml://registries/HuggingFace/models/cardiffnlp-twitter-roberta-base-sentiment/versions/19) and in this there is no option to define the schema.. although it does have an swagger point available

That is may be the model is from hugging face and no signature will be present. But still while deploying model to endpoint there it will be defined. Let me check and update

For in built models the signature will be be predefined and can not give custom scoring script. So, try register the model in workspace and deploy it with custom script.
